# Dynamic drop-down issues in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to select the selected 'option' from a dynamic drop-down in a table td  where the tr iterates 18 times. Placing ngModel in the 'Select' causes all rows to use the same selection! How can I make each  independent using ngModel to send the data to the ts file?

HTML:

```
<tr class="row header" *ngFor = "let par of Course; let i=index" >
<td class="col">{{i +1}}</td>
<td class="col1">{{par.Index}}</td>
<td class="col">{{par.Par}}</td>
<td class="col2">{{getPoints(par)}}</td>
<td class="col">{{getShots(par)}}</td>
<td class="col3" ><select [(ngModel)]="sel" (change)="onChangeScore(sel)">
<option  *ngFor= "let s of items" >{{s}}</option></select></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You are iterating over X elements but you are using the same variable `sel` for each `par`. I suggest you assign selection to `par` so you can easily get it from `Course` array. To do so, replace `sel` with `par.sel`. I hope it'll work

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! Nearly there I hope. To pass the selection to the ts file is it just a case of 'this.par.sel'? (sorry I am a newbie to Ionic 2.     onChangeScore(par.sel) {console.log(this.par.sel);
}

Comment: To pass the selection to the ts file you need to change `onChangeScore(par.sel)` too. Then in your ts file just onChangeScore(selection) {console.log(selection); }

Comment: Sebastian, THANK YOU SO MUCH! I have spent hours on this. Much appreciated

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Consider accepting it so others could potentially use it in similar cases :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over X elements but you are using the same variable `sel` for each `par`. I suggest you assign selection to `par` so you can easily get it from `Course` array. To do so, replace this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="sel" (change)="onChangeScore(sel)">
```

to this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="par.sel" (change)="onChangeScore(par.sel)">
```

Then in your ts file you can easily acces it by:

```
onChangeScore(selection) {
    console.log(selection);
}
```

Glad I could help